# Merging commands with log file in batch program

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to run something like this:

```
tasklist /s 192.168.0.0 >> tasklist.log && tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 >> tasklist.log
```

From a script called: `tasklist.bat`, It's throwing multiple errors of:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Shouldn't `&&` wait for the previous command to finish before executing? How do I fix this problem?

**Not sure if this helps, but here is the full script:**

```
echo Server1 >> tasklist.log
echo ------------------- >> tasklist.log
tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 >> tasklist.log && tasklist /s 192.168.1.2 >> tasklist.log && tasklist /s 192.168.1.3 >> tasklist.log
echo ------------------- >> tasklist.log
```

**Also, I noticed this extra `1` when I see the command prompt text:**

```
tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 1>>tlog.log
```

Something to do with >> with tasklist is producing a "1" in the log.

**Here is the log:**

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 1>>tlog.log

C:\Users\username\Desktop>tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 1>>tlog.log

C:\Users\username\Desktop>tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 1>>tlog.log
```

Comment: It works on my computer. Try using a different file name. Maybe another process has tasklist.log locked.

Comment: see my updated answer and tell me if that is ok to do

Comment: Still no issues running your full script. Have you tried changing all the "tasklist.log" to a different file name?

Comment: hey, ya I just tried changing the log file name and I still get the same errors

Comment: Perhaps you have a TASKLIST.BAT that is being executed instead of the standard TASKLIST.EXE. If so, then rename your batch file to a name that does not match a standard command.

Comment: @dbenham THAT WAS THE PROBLEM! Please post your answer so others can see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparantly you have a TASKLIST.BAT script that is being executed instead of the desired external TASKLIST.EXE command. Rename the batch script to resolve the problem.

Comment: yes that script was the name of the one I was running :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use it this way:

```
(
echo Server1
echo -------------------
tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 && tasklist /s 192.168.1.2 && tasklist /s 192.168.1.3
echo -------------------
) > tasklist.log
```

Comment: this produced the same error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Comment: It turned out to be TASKLIST.BAT that is being executed instead of the standard TASKLIST.EXE. Rename the batch file to a name that does not match a standard command.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, it looks like tasklist always returns exit code 0 (success) even if there is an error, so there's no point in using && with it. You can just break it apart into multiple lines. You should see if the problem recurs when you do that.

```
echo Server1 >> tasklist.log
echo ------------------- >> tasklist.log

tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 >> tasklist.log
tasklist /s 192.168.1.2 >> tasklist.log
tasklist /s 192.168.1.3 >> tasklist.log

echo ------------------- >> tasklist.log
```

> Also, I noticed this extra 1 when I see the command prompt text

The 1 is referring to the stdout stream. Every process has three streams open by default: stdin (0, console input), stdout (1, normal program output), stderr (2, error message output). When you don't specify a stream in your output redirection, it defaults to 1.

Comment: Actually this is happening if I run the command in a prompt. Something to do with >> with tasklist is producing a "1" in the log. C:\Users\username\Desktop>tasklist /s 192.168.1.1 1>>tlog.log

Comment: The 1 is expected. I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: ok so any ideas? or is tasklist just not supposed to be piped to a txt file? thanks for your help btw

Comment: I'm out of ideas. If the error is still happening, try Aacini's suggestion. Redirecting tasklist works fine on my computer.

Comment: It turned out to be TASKLIST.BAT that is being executed instead of the standard TASKLIST.EXE. Rename the batch file to a name that does not match a standard command.